# a queries of Sensors on i2c

Tags: i2c

I saw the sensors on i2c statement and problem as following.

```
 -Interrupt or trigger sent OOB to host using GPIO wire

 -Host timestpamps or triggers the event

  ● host controls the accuracy and latency.
```

But actually, I want to know that

1.What is the OOB?

2.What is the timestapms?

Comment: What is the context?  Where is the quote from?  If your question is about something that you have read somewhere, then please add a link or reference so that the rest of us could read that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that OOB in this context means "Out Of Band" meaning it is sent using a separate mechanism from that used for data transfer.

I2C can transfer data but does not inherently have any way of a slave sending an alert back to the master, so a separate line can be used going back to a GPIO (General Purpose Input/Output) at the master CPU.

"timestpamps" is a mis-spelling of "timestamps" meaning to record the time at which the host receives the signal. Or alternatively the host can act on the signal directly.

If the host puts a timestamp on the signal it will probably place it in a queue to be processed later - the timestamp will inform the processing software when the signal arrived.  This implies that the host has a concept of time, such as a register that is incremented whenever an interrupt is received from a real-time clock.

Comment: Thanks Sir, would you please let me know what kind of job is needed to timestamps? I think might host use timestamp for accuracy and latency. But I'm not sure.

Comment: As I know, the timestamps are not existed in i2c specification. Where does it come from as define the 'timestamps'?